# Prove a law of excluded middle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Need help with proving of a law of excluded middle from a formula  ¬(¬A ∧ ¬B ∧ C) → (A ∨ B ∨ ¬C). I can use only 10 axioms :
[these axioms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGtzW.jpg)

Thank you very much!

Comment: +1 just for showing your axioms -- for some reason it is very hard to get most askers to do that. But it would be even better if you had also written something about your own attempts to solve this.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you can use 10 axioms plus the law of the excluded  middle (so 11 axioms)?  Otherwise, the statement is not provable since it is not constructively true but all the 10 axioms listed are constructively true.

Comment: @DanielV You are right, we can use only 10(!) axioms, and 11th(law of excluded middle) we should prove. All I need is step by step proving ;)

Comment: @newfag You cannot prove LEM from those 10 axioms.

Comment: @DanielV No, we should prove LEM from the formula by using 10 axioms

Comment: @newfag Oh I see, you said *from* the formula.  Sorry for the misunderstanding.  Henning's approach is a good one then.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint.** Instantiate the formula with $A$, $B$, and $C$ all being $P$. Then you can prove its left-hand side using $A_{10}$.

Comment: To be honest, I can't understand your idea. Can you explain it in detail? I am beginner in propositional calculus, sorry :)

Comment: You're assuming, among other formulas, $\neg(\neg P\land \neg P\land P)\to (P\lor P\lor \neg P)$. Can you find an instance of $A_{10}$ that will conclude $\neg(\neg P \land \neg P\land P)$ for you? Can you get from $P\lor P\lor \neg P$ to $P\lor \neg P$, which is the law of excluded middle?